# Grep a pattern from file

Tags: shell, command-line, express, grep

I am trying to use grep to pull out express values.

I run eXpress and I have my .xprs tab separated value file which looks like this:

```
bundle_id   target_id   length  eff_length  tot_counts  uniq_counts est_counts  eff_counts  ambig_distr_alpha   ambig_distr_beta    fpkm    fpkm_conf_low   fpkm_conf_high  solvable
1   Contig14365 310 106.787904  85  85  85.000000   246.750792  0.000000e+00    0.000000e+00    147.370523  147.370523  147.370523  T
2   Singlet_45262   346 232.432874  109 37  89.933541   133.875234  1.998601e+00    7.198885e-01    71.637085   51.273440   92.000730   T
2   Singlet_68764   236 119.092916  74  2   21.066459   41.746263   6.254955e+00    1.736541e+01    32.750608   0.142967    65.358248   T
3   Contig1270  736 500.694431  50  0   0.125252    0.184116    1.000000e+00    1.000000e+00    0.046316    0.000000    0.759071    F
3   Contig1271  851 628.717767  57  9   43.657462   59.092492   4.701649e-01    1.810055e-01    12.856315   4.051524    21.661106   T
3   Singlet_69558   790 555.880836  50  0   15.217286   21.626318   1.000000e+00    1.000000e+00    5.068381    0.000000    12.670313   F
```

I want to get non-codingRNA-specific express values so I thought to use:

```
grep -f <list of ncRNAs contigs> <express file>
```

I made a file with ncRNAs contigs IDs which looks like this:

```
Singlet_51268
Singlet_63946
Singlet_70630
Singlet_72272
Singlet_60543
Contig11105
Singlet_18043
Singlet_64779
Singlet_50335
Singlet_39678
Singlet_21655
Singlet_5438
Singlet_6400
Contig4197
Singlet_17193
Singlet_55710
Singlet_70948
Singlet_25172
Singlet_65515
Singlet_30239
Singlet_54617
Singlet_11188
Contig14540
```

Since my ncRNAs are 577, I expect to end up with a .xprs file with 577 rows but I ended up with a .xprs file of 701 Contigs.

So I have 124 Contigs that do not correspond to my ncRNAs.

How could I pull out ncRNAs-specific values? I tried playing around with grep but I can't fix it.

Any suggestions?

THanks

Comment: Try using `-E <regex>` for better matches. You can also use `-o` `Show only the part of a matching line that matches PATTERN.`

Comment: grep -w -f <list of ncRNAs contigs> <express file> seems to work fine. Thanks for help though

Answer (score 1):

If you can use `awk` then this should work -

```
awk 'NR==FNR {a[$1]++; next} $2 in a' file xprs
```

Comment: I used grep -w -f <list of ncRNAs contigs> <express file> and it worked fine!Thanks for help though

Comment: @user1819854 You should post that as an answer and accept it. That serves as a good reference for others. :)

Answer (score 1):

I used

`grep -w -f <list of ncRNAs contigs> <express file>`

and it worked fine!

**NOTE:**

`-w` limits grep to **WHOLE WORDS ONLY**, so grep doesn't search for "12345" and also pull out "123456".